# Thinkpad T61 in 2011

Tags: thinkpad

I've just bought a used T61 for a good price ($200). The laptop is still on good condition,
and plan to use for another 1 or 2 years (so from 2011 to 2012). Main uses are doing web development, and probably a .NET development.

Is the machine (C2D 2.40ghz, 3GB DDR2 RAM, 250HD) could handle these tasks? I'm saving for a new X or W Series Thinkpad and it would probably take me year to get one.

Comment: Great deal on the T61, where did you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a T61 with just about the same spec - I use it for a full Visual Studio Development suite running emulators for Windows Phone 7 and ASP Web development.  It also has enough grunt to run a basic VM for some testing.  The only issue you might come across is if you want to do any high end 3D development.

Comment: +1  have similar system and only issue is screen resolution but with an external monitor all is well.  And 3D is a challenge.